# I'm writing the command processing part of the tui for a basic task manager/todo list application

Tags: rust, error-handling, pattern-matching, string-processing

The idea is that the TUI struct handles what gets printed to the terminal (I will make it pretty in the future, right now I'm just building its core functionalities) and for processing input. It's what interfaces with the TaskManager struct, which stores, adds, removes, and modifies tasks.

Here are the Task and TaskManager structs (priority and status are just enums)

```rust
pub struct Task {
    id: u32,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    priority: Priority,
    status: Status,
}

pub struct TaskManager {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
}
impl TaskManager {
    pub fn new() -> Self { ... }
    pub fn new_task(...) {...}
    pub fn remove_task(...) {...}
    pub fn get_task_by_id(...) -> Option<&mut Task> {...}
    pub fn get_task_by_title(...) -> Option<&mut Task> {...}
    pub fn change_task_status(...) -> Result<(), TaskNotFoundError> {...}
    pub fn change_task_priority(...) -> Result<(), TaskNotFoundError> {...}
    pub fn log_tasks(...) {...}
}
```

The `TUI::process_input` function is what I want to improve because right now it's just a nesting mess because of error handling and its logic in general.

I don't necessarily want to keep this syntax, this is just what I first came up with to make the input processing part easier

```rust
fn process_input(&mut self, input: &str) -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut binding = input.split(':');
    let cmd = binding.next().unwrap_or("");

    if let Some(arguments) = binding.next() {
        let args_binding = arguments.split(',').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        let mut args = args_binding.iter();
        match cmd {
            "help" => {
                println!(
r#"
Every command follows this syntax:
the name of the command, a semicolon (always) and an optional list of arguments depending on the command.
<command>:<arg1,arg2,...>

List of commands:
* help:
* list:
* add:<priority>,<title>
* remove:<id>
* description:<id>,<description>
* priority:<id>,<new_priority>
* status:<id>,<new_status>
* exit:
"#
                    );
            }
            "list" => {
                self.display();
            },
            "add" => {
                let priority: &str = &(*args.next().unwrap_or(&"low")).to_lowercase();
                let title: &str = args
                    .next()
                    .ok_or(format!("task title is missing..."))?
                    .strip_suffix('\n')
                    .ok_or(format!("could not parse task title..."))?;

                self.tm.new_task(
                        match Priority::from_str(priority) {
                            Ok(p) => p,
                            Err(e) => return Err(format!("invalid priority argument...")),
                        },
                        title,
                    );
            },
            "remove" => {
                let id = args
                        .next()
                        .ok_or(format!("task id missing..."))?
                        .strip_suffix('\n')
                        .ok_or(format!("could not read task id..."))?
                        .parse::<u32>()
                        .ok().ok_or(format!("could not parse task id..."))?;
                self.tm.remove_task(TaskSelector::Id(id));
            },
            "description" => { },           // <--------------
            "priority" => {
                let id = args
                    .next()
                    .ok_or(format!("task id is missing..."))?
                    .parse::<u32>()
                    .ok().ok_or(format!("could not parse task id..."))?;
                let priority = match Priority::from_str(args
                                                        .next()
                                                        .ok_or(format!("priority argument is missing..."))?
                                                        .strip_suffix('\n')
                                                        .ok_or(format!("could not read priority argument..."))?)
                {
                    Ok(p) => p,
                    Err(_) => return Err(format!("invalid priority argument...")),
                };
                self.tm
                    .change_task_priority(TaskSelector::Id(id), priority)
                    .ok().ok_or(format!("could not find task with id '{}'", id))?;
            },
            "status" => {
                let id = args
                    .next()
                    .ok_or(format!("task id is missing..."))?
                    .parse::<u32>()
                    .ok().ok_or(format!("could not parse task id..."))?;
                let status = match Status::from_str(args
                                                    .next()
                                                    .ok_or(format!("status argument is missing..."))?
                                                    .strip_suffix('\n')
                                                    .ok_or(format!("could not read status argument..."))?)
                {
                    Ok(s) => s,
                    Err(_) => return Err(format!("invalid status argument...")),
                };
                self.tm
                    .change_task_status(TaskSelector::Id(id), status)
                    .ok().ok_or(format!("could not find task with id '{}'", id))?;
            },
            "exit" => {
                // save tasks to file and exit
            },
            "" => { /* do nothing */ },
            _ => return Err(format!("'{}' is not a valid command...", cmd)),
        }
    } else {
        return Err(format!("command arguments are missing..."));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

what could I improve about this function?
(if you want to see the full code I created a repository: https://github.com/trapano-monogamo/taskman/tree/master)

Comment: First and foremost, you could use existing libraries like [`clap`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/) to implement the command line parsing, instead of reinventing the wheel.